# Should I do a check or just set a record in Redis?

Tags: database-design, redis

When a users plays one of my apps I'm saving their session to a daily, weekly, monthly and alltime tables. I'm wondering if it would be smart to see if the user is already in the table before inserting. Assuming they aren't in the table it would need to do a read and write where the other way no matter what there is only a write.

Answer (score 0):

It basically depends on your requirement.
Due to lack of information I assume that when you say daily ,weekly,monthly and alltime tables you are referring to the TTL values.

Then there are two scenarios

1. if a latest visit by user must extend the expiry time of the key

So if you need to overwrite those keys' TTL you don't need a read (if a latest visit by user must extend the expiry time of the key)

2. Subsequent visits must not change the TTL

Else if the session expiry time must remain same( from the first time of visit) then a GET must be used to read if the value exists before SET.Depending on concurrency requirement these two operations can be atomic or not.

P.S As mentioned before that this answer is based on some assumptions.Please share more details about your KEY structure

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. I'm not using TTL I'm using 4 differnet tables players:d, players:w, players:m and players:a. When a user starts the app I just insert their session into the 4 locations. I have a cron setup to run every night at midnight that just deletes the players:d table and if it's the first of the week it deletes the players:w and first of the month players:m.

Comment: just let me confirm one thing ,you are using Redis right?
If you are using it then may I suggest you to look into the TTL feature of the keys. 
and again in any case it all depends on requirement.
**You need to ask yourself one question whether or not these session values are affected by later visits ?**

looking at your comment it seems that they do not and your cron Job setup actually eliminates the need to check(as you do not set TTL) if it already exists.
So you can simply put the key without a care in the world

Comment: Yes I'm using Redis. I use TTL for some records but I haven't tested performance on the TTL vs just deleting the whole table. I would assume the TTL would require more load on the server but I could be wrong. In my head a cron job to just delete the hash key seemed like it would be better. The session value will be the same every time so I don't care if it overwrites it every time.

Comment: TTL has no overload as far as I know also it provides finer control over keys .but as you know it's duration.
If I may suggest you could use your sessionid as key with some prefix  and required TTL and dummy value everything will take care of itself.

Comment: @Dave could you please let me know what you decided and why.
I am also working on something similar. So just curious

Comment: I ran some benchmarks and found that it really depends on what your situation is. For example if you thought that a majority of the users would be returning users then doing a check proves to be faster. However if you're unsure about what percentage of users will be returning then it would be faster to just do the inserts. As for the TTL I opted to just go with a cron to remove the daily table. It's just 1 redis call and it prevents me from having to calculate and set the correct TTL on every record.